# How to use serialize to serialize only some field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a serializer

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_brand = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    product_type = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to use the same serializer to other serializer but I only need to get the product_type from it i.e.:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer( # only get product_type)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

The wanted result would be:

```
{
    ...
    "product": {
        "product_type": "Random"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a serializer which supports [***dynamic field altering***](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields).

Comment: If I have a choice, I would create a new serializer which returns only a few selected fields. If I need **only one field**, I would use **`SerializerMethodField`**. This will enhance the decoupling behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion! I guess I would go with your suggestion since it would enhance performance as you've said.

Comment: Great. But, one correction, It's not about the *performance*, it's about the *readability* and *maintainability*

Comment: Ohhh. Okay then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get this data:

```
{
    ...
    "product": {
        "product_type": "Random"
    }
}
```

You may use this serializers:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_brand = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_brand', )

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Also, you may simplify it:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_type = serializers.CharField(source="product.product_type")
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

You will get that result:

```
{
    ...
    "product_type": "Random"
}
```